# Adding Custom Attributes To the Jquery Slider? autoplay slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can I Add Custom Attributes To the Jquery Slider named Fullscreen slider? I want my slider to autoplay, How should i do so?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){

            jQuery('#slider').fullscreen_slider({
              easing: 'easeOutQuad',
              handle_width: 100, //Prev next show width
              speed: 'slow'  // Three options only.
            });

});
jQuery(window).resize(function() {

           jQuery('#slider').fullscreen_slider('resize');

});
```

Comment: pls add a link to the plugin which you are using

Comment: No plugin. It is simply addedthrough the jQuery code which i have given above

Comment: i think so you are using this one https://github.com/htmldrive/Fullscreen-image-slider-jquery-plugin/blob/master/js/fullscreen_slider.js

Comment: Yes You are right. Is there anything i can do in this?

Comment: There is too much code in the link mentioned by you. But there is no such in mine.

Comment: I think http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-Elements-Fullscreen-Plugin-with-jQuery/examples/  this is it. Please have a look.

Comment: i think the plugin file is fullscreen_slider.js and looking at the plugin you need the call this method caller.play($(this)) or the caller.forward() function repeatedly , there do not seem any method to play the slider on page load